# Python mock patch a function decorator's parameter value

Tags: python, django, mocking

Lets say I have a settings.py

```
value = 10
```

and I have a function like this with a decorator inside module a

```
import settings

@some_decorator(repeat=settings.value):
def do_work():
   print settings.value
   // prints 1
   ...
```

In unittest I am trying to patch the settings.value to 1 like this:

```
with patch('settings.value', new=1):
    do_work()
```

But the do_work function still gets repeated 10 times, I don't think the parameter of the decorator was patched because it gets executed before the unittest starts. How do I change this?

Comment: Just in case: is it django settings you are talking about?

Comment: @alecxe not exactly, it's an App setting in v1.7, I just simplified it for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short *you cannot patch a **value** passed to a decorator parameter*.

Anyway, your patch does not work because when `do_work()` is decorated `settings.value` was `10` and you cannot change it after that: it is not a variable that is resolved at run time but just a value (not mutable).

Of course, when `do_work()` is executed `settings.value` is `1` and then it prints `1` but the value used in decorated `do_work()` is still `10` and cannot change.

How you can work around it? If you cannot change the decorator I cannot see any way to do it, otherwise if `repeat` in the decorator is a callable, it will be resolved every time you call the decorated function.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the settings?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings

```
@override_settings(LOGIN_URL='/other/login/')
def test_login(self):
```

Comment: I am curious if it would be too late to modify the settings since the module gets parsed before changing the settings?