# Patch a function called inside a decorator

Tags: python, patch, python-decorators, python-click

I have a function called `get_choices()` - that makes an api call - that is called inside a `click.Choice()` decorator for a `click.Command()` function called `cli()`.

I want to test the command function `cli()` using click's `CliRunner().invoke()` method but avoid the api call inside `get_choices()`.

Below is a minimal code to use. Make sure to have click installed using `pip install click`.

**cli.py**

```py
from click import command, option, Choice


def get_choices():
    print("making an api call")
    return ["name_1", "name_2"]


@command()
@option(
    "--name",
    prompt=True,
    type=Choice(choices=get_choices()), # api call is made here
)

def cli(name):
    pass # Doesn't matter what happens here
```

**test_cli.py**

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
import click
from click.testing import CliRunner


# This avoids the api call when importing cli below 
# but makes an api call itself when loading the module
patch("cli.get_choices", get_test_choices).start() 


def test_cli_behaves():
    runner = CliRunner()
    import cli

    # Replaces prod choices with test choices
    # I want to avoid using params[0]
    cli.cli.params[0].type = click.Choice(["name_test"]) 

    result = runner.invoke(cli.cli, args=["--name", "name_test"])
    print(result.stdout)
    assert result.exit_code == 0
    assert False
```

Is there a way to patch `get_choices()` before it's called inside the decorator when loading the module ?

I would like to avoid:

- Any api call
- Accessing `cli.cli.params[0]` since it's not clean and becomes cumbersome when there are many options added to the cli.

I am testing by attaching a debugger to the test and adding a breakpoint on the api call in `get_choices()` and can confirm an api call is made on the patch line or the import line if the patch isn't used.

I've read a lot of questions/answers about patching with decorators on stackoverflow, most notably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667567/can-i-patch-a-python-decorator-before-it-wraps-a-function) which I've used to inspire my current solution, but none provides what I really want.

Edit: Does [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26991122/14163702) also apply in my case ?